How can I Mint and Transfer token programmatically?
So I have created this test transaction using Safe {WALLET} transaction builder dashboard feature, it does 2 transactions:

Mint an ecr20 token
Transfer this to another account.

All this takes place in sepolia test net.
Is there an endpoint in the safe-transaction-base-sepolia that I can use to do the above operation programmatically? if not, is there a sdk to achieve such thing?

You can use the /api/v1/safes/{address}/multisig-transactions/ endpoint to submit a transaction via the Safe Transaction Service. A TypeScript client also exists, with a method to interact with this endpoint.
Alternatively, you can also use Safe{Core} SDK's protocol kit to create a transaction that will be submitted to your safe.
To get the data field you can copy the "Raw data" string in the transaction builder (Advanced Details) as shown below:

Hope it helps; Best, Louis

Thanks Louis!
How do I come up with the value in the data field? I see both API and SDK accept a string there

Just edited the answer to reflect that! Best, Louis

Thanks Louis. I implemented this using sdk to create the transaction then api-kit to propose it, but it turns out that we can't create transactions unless there's 1 signature to it. which is a dealbreaker for us :/
Now I'm checking this other library of yours app-sdk. Perhaps we can make use of that to have something similar to transaction-builder app. We can create/propose transactions from there right? that way whoever proposes the transaction will sign it for the first time so it will be acceptable.
